# How could a turbocharger experience over-boosting due to cold oil?

Tags: engine

How can cold oil cause a turbocharged engine's automatic waste gate to stick, leading to over-boosting?

Diagrams I've found online for waste gates don't appear to indicate a connection between it and cylinder oil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wastegate system uses engine oil pressure to drive the wastegate actuator, and this oil pressure is metered to the actuator by a controller that senses manifold pressure and throttle position and admits more or less oil to the actuator to drive the wastegate butterfly valve, to achieve the manifold pressure commanded by the throttle opening.

The responsiveness of the control system is sensitive to oil viscosity.  When the oil is cold, the controller and actuator is sluggish and laggy because of the thick oil, which can lead to overboosting when the throttle is opened quickly and the wastegate is unable to keep up, resulting in excess flow through the turbine and excess boost.

[image]

Comment: Is this applicable to all turbochargers or is this method just one of several and this particular one is one that uses engine oil, while others do not?  The example you present above: is this purely mechanical, or is it digital?

Comment: No this is a traditional mechanical turbocharging system and is still pretty much what you will see on most piston engines even today although maybe the latest designs are going with digital/electrical control.  If the manual for the airplane has the admonition you mention about cold oil, it'll be this type of system.  These engines still use a Bendix mechanical fuel injection system designed in the 50s.  It's a very conservative business because simple and reliable and easy to fix is the priority.  Solid state magnetos are out there but have only been around for about 20 years.

Comment: Notice the flow to the actuator comes from the oil COOLER.  On a very cold day this oil may be more viscous before the engine warms up.  An actuator oil temperature gauge may be in order.